# How to set default lang if lang doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

How to set default lang if lang doesn't exist . It should redirect to default lang I use `mcamara/laravel-localization package`

I want to set en = default lang and if I type url isn't exist I want to redirect into en

```
example 

1 www.test.com/en/new

2 www.test.com/cn/new <- this url empty it should redirect into url 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel comes with `en` as default and you can specify the fallback in `config/app.php`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Locale Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
| by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
| to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
|
*/

'locale' => 'en',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Fallback Locale
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
| is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
| the language folders that are provided through your application.
|
*/

'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

Comment: I already set it in app.php but when I type www.test.com/cn/new  it not redirect into en it go to page 404